# Javascript variable scoping with IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm new to Javascript and trying to loop over the array inside a for loop with a `setTimeout` this is a portion of code so i have 100msec by default.
I'm expecting output to be 1,2,3 but all its printing is undefined 3 times.
if someone can help me explaining why that will be helpful.

```
var allCars=['Car1','Car2','Car3'];
for(var i = 0; i < allCars.length; i++)
{
  (function(temp){  
  setTimeout(function(temp){
      console.log(allCars[temp]);
  },100)})(i);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't pass any arguments to the callback. Since you declared the callback with the parameter `temp`, `temp` will be `undefined`. If you expect `temp` to refer to the outer parameter of your IIFE, how do you expected JavaScript to know which one to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` does not pass any parameter (unless you specify one) to its callback, but you're specifying one parameter named `temp`, which hides the `temp` in the outer scope.

```
var allCars=['Car1','Car2','Car3'];
for(var i = 0; i < allCars.length; i++)
{
  (function(temp){  
  setTimeout(function(temp){    // This temp hides the temp on the line above
      console.log(allCars[temp]);
  },100)})(i);
}
```

Simply remove the parameter from the callback passed to `setTimeout` to allow the outer `temp` to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated code which shall produce correct result. Problem you having when you are passing a parameter to the `setTimeout` 
here is updated code

```
var allCars=['Car1','Car2','Car3'];
for(var i = 0; i < allCars.length; i++)
{
  (function(temp){  
  setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(allCars[temp]);
  },100)})(i);
}
```